# Does the if false statement always return undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently developing a website and plan on using JavaScript.

```
function func() {
    if (false) {
        var a = 'goodbye';
    }
    console.log(a);
}
```

This above example shows scope and I would like to know how you would prevent this coming out undefined and why this would be the case.

I've researched mdn, w3 schools and varius sites but they are either to specific or too general.

It would be great for people who use JavaScript regularly but are not the team leads to have this resource - and I plan to use this knowledge to make a web page using front end languages (JavaScript, html, CSS, etc.)

[online-editor](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Please feel free to add more tags if appropriate!

Comment: Add a *return statement?*

Comment: You don't return anything in your function

Comment: Even if you do `return a` from that function you'll end up with `undefined`. that's because You're declaring `a` in a block that will never execute.

Comment: you are not setting a, `console.log`ing `a` after that is like `console.log`ing `undefined`

Comment: where would I need to place so that it could execute? Again, this is a theory related question.

Comment: @Luca, could I not just switch things arund and the code will work?

Comment: Not really, there isn't much to switch around... An `if(false)` doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: Just use `let` and you will never have such headaches again...

Comment: @JonasW. how would `let` help here? Just replacing `var` with `let` doesn't do anything

Comment: @luca `console.log(a)` will throw an error. So to make it work, you would need to move the declaration one scope up, and then the scoping gets more clear.

Comment: @JonasW. So, you are admitting, that simply changing `var` to `let` doesn't end the problem ;)

Comment: Me? JSFiddle, Codepen, the JS Console of your browser

Comment: @luca `I would like to know how you would prevent this coming out undefined` -> definetly done. `let` solves everything ;)

Comment: @JonasW. Do you think my new edits provide an in scope answer? The edits are provided in the new answer.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you're seeing `undefined` when the condition in that `if` is false is that `var` is *hoisted* to the top of the function and variables get `undefined` as their default value.

After hoisting, your code is this:

```
function func() {
    var a; // Defaults to `undefined`
    if (false) {
        a = 'goodbye';
    }
    console.log(a);
}
```

Since the condition is false, `a`'s default value is never changed.

More about `var` hoisting on my anemic little blog: [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

Comment: @Li357: Well, we very nearly can...soon. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are confused with how if statement works,

```
if(Condition comes out to true)
{
 This will work
}
```

Other wise it will not work, you have entered Condition to be false by default so the if block is not executed. 
And as you have defined "a" inside the if block, the variable "a" is never getting defined as the if block is not executed .
thus you are getting undefined when you are logging a